# Adobe Acrobat save PDF files to Sharepoint (Online Account)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, sharepoint-2010

I do the following:

1. Open PDF document in **Adobe Acrobat XI Version 11.0.10**
2. **File** > **Save As...**
3. **Save to Online Account** > **New Account...**
4. Check **SharePoint**
5. Type in library path example: http://sharepoint/documents
6. Click **Continue**
7. Click **Save**

Error: You cannot save to this location. Please choose another folder or document library.

I hope someone could help me, thanks in advance.